# When backgroundworker completes, how to give priority to update the UI thread?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a background worker I'm using to run through a large function in hopes of quickening my window load and responsiveness.  When I put this function in the backgrounderworker's doWork event I'm just wondering if there's anyway I can prioritize that text to update as soon as the BGW is complete rather than waiting for the UI thread to finish and then update the textbox.  Is this possible?  I only ask because it seems like it's taking quite some to update the textbox after running through the function(which takes about 1.5-2s) but even if I start the BGW to begin even before the window loads(takes a good 5 seconds to load), it's still the last item on my window to update so I would like to(if possible), halt the UI thread from updating the UI until I update with what this function returns, then continue updating the rest of the labels.

Also, is there anyway to update two separate items at once or is it restricted to the one UI thread?

Comment: BackgroundWorkers won't make things go faster, they just provide a way to run code without blocking the GUI.  That being said, it sounds like you are still running code that blocks the GUI since you are `waiting for the UI thread to finish`.  You will have to post some code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update UI elements, you have to do it on the UI thread. When the `BackgroundWorker` is finished, the `RunWorkerCompleted` event is raised on the UI thread. If the UI thread is busy doing something, then the completed event has to wait. In general, there's no safe way to interrupt the UI thread, make it process the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, and then go back to what it was doing.

UI elements *must* be updated from the UI thread. So you can't update two separate items at once.

I don't know how your initialization is structured, but if you have one group of items that you can initialize before the BGW is finished, and another group that can't update before the BGW is done, then do the first group and stop. Then have the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler do its update and all the rest of the updates. So it would look something like:

```
FormLoad()
    start background worker
    do first group of updates

RunWorkerCompletedHandler()
    update from BGW calculation
    do rest of updates
```